# Prove $f(x)=9x^2-5y^2-34$ has no integral roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, roots

Prove $f(x)=9x^2-5y^2-34$ has no integral roots. I have tried working this mod 2, 3, 4, 5, and 17, and some random others, to no avail. It is for a graduate course, so I am thinking maybe I tried to make it too easy, but I have not learned of any other ways to solve such problems, nor could I find any other ways in my research online or in my abstract algebra books.

Answer (score 3):

Mod 4 should have worked:
$$x^2 - y^2 \equiv 2\pmod 4$$
and notice the left-hand side can be anything  *except* two.

Comment: okay, I somehow ended up with 2, but I am looking now and realize I had done one of the calculations mod 3.